# Ionic 6 php API on remote MySql server

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I got a simple project and decided to start and learn ionic, im trying to take data from remote sql server.

Php API backend (getData.php)

```js
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
header('Content-Length: 0');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dataapi") or die('could not connect DB');

$data = array();
$q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `tbl_data`");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($q)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
echo mysqli_error($con);
```

Services API (api.service.ts)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  headers: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { 
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.headers.append("Accept", 'aplication/json');
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'aplication/json');
    this.headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  }
  getDatas() {
    return this.http.get('https://myweb/getData.php');
    // return this.http.get('http://localhost/phpapi/getData.php');
  }

}
```

App Module (app.module.ts)

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

debug page ts (debug.page.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-debug',
  templateUrl: './debug.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./debug.page.scss'],
})
export class DebugPage implements OnInit {

  datas: any = [];

  constructor(public _apiService: ApiService) { 
    this.getDatas();
   }

   getFoods() {
     this._apiService.getDatas().subscribe((res:any) => {
       console.log("SUCCESS ===", res);
       this.datas = res;
     },(error:any) => {
       console.log("ERROR===", error);
     })
   }
```

debug page html (debug.page.html)

```
<ion-item lines="inset" *ngFor="let data of datas">
  <ion-label>
    <p>Name: {{data.name}}</p>
    <p>Rating: {{data.rating}}</p>
    <p>Category: {{data.categories}}</p>
  </ion-label>
```

First problem:
It works fine on localhost (im using xampp) but not on remote host

```
console log : SUCCESS === null
```

this console log success === null appear when I set wrong database user or password too.

Second problem:
The "works" part while on localhost not working on android device, only on browser. Already tried solving using local IP instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

find a  solution, it works after removing this header access control lines:

```html
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
header('Content-Length: 0');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```